# Not supporting .mp2 files in Android Nougat and Oreo using FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am developing an android app using FFmpeg [https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java]

Successfully working all app function on 4.1 to 6.0 android version but I am facing following error for Android version - 7.0(Nougat),7.1.1(Nougat) and 8.0(Oreo)

Following error is coming when I select an .mp2 file from my android app for Nougat and Oreo. And I use FFmpeg for conversion purposes.
Eg. - .wav to .mp2 and vice-versa

Android Studio - 3.0,
compileSdkVersion - 23,
targetSdkVersion - 23,

```
I/FFmpeg: Loading FFmpeg for armv7-neon CPU
I/FFMPEG convert start: -i //storage//emulated//0//sample-160kbps.mp2 //storage//emulated//0//sample-160kbps_copy2play.wav
D/FFmpeg: Running publishing updates method
I/FFMPEG convert progress: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/com.yellowtec.uplinkixm.app/files/ffmpeg": /data/data/com.yellowtec.uplinkixm.app/files/ffmpeg: has text relocations-i //storage//emulated//0//sample-160kbps.mp2 //storage//emulated//0//sample-160kbps_copy2play.wav
E/FFMPEG convert error: command:: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/com.yellowtec.uplinkixm.app/files/ffmpeg": /data/data/com.yellowtec.uplinkixm.app/files/ffmpeg: has text relocations
                                  -i //storage//emulated//0//sample-160kbps.mp2 //storage//emulated//0//sample-160kbps_copy2play.wav
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/MYMediaPlayer: I got an ERROR 
                 java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1093)
                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1039)
                     at com.yellowtec.uplinkixm.app.Utils.FfmpegEncoder.checkAndPlayFile(FfmpegEncoder.java:314)
                     at com.yellowtec.uplinkixm.app.Utils.DownloadHandler.handleMessage(DownloadHandler.java:249)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

So my question is why this error is coming and how to solve this error for Nougat and Oreo. And also I am confuse because this media player error is due to android media player function[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html] or 
due to FFmpeg.

Comment: See second comment by Alex Cohn in [Overlay image on video using ffmpeg in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47543543/1109017).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: good catch! Yes, this **ffmpeg** binary can only work on Android 4 till 6. I believe that **ffmpeg 3.3** will work, try the prebuilt binaries [on GitHub](https://github.com/kesha-antonov/ffmpeg-android-java), or build it yourself.

Comment: @AlexCohn I am trying to build ffmpeg3.4 binaries and I got following error - " ./configure: 906: ./configure: /home/intecore/Sujay/android_ndk_r16/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
C compiler test failed."n i refer following sites: "http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/07/30/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-with-x264-for-android/" "https://yesimroy.gitbooks.io/android-note/content/compile_ffmpeg_for_android.html"

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm trying to build ffmpeg3.4 binaries and I got following error - " ./configure: 906: ./configure: /home/intecore/Sujay/android_ndk_r16/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
C compiler test failed."n i refer follwg sites: "http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/07/30/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-with-x264-for-android/" "https://yesimroy.gitbooks.io/android-note/content/compile_ffmpeg_for_android.html"

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you are right about x264 build options, but luckily they are irrelevant for **mp2 → wav** conversion in this topic. I would suggest the TS to build ffmpeg w/o video codecs. An additional incentive to avoid x264 is to have leaner licensing.

Comment: @AlexCohn: see your this comment - good catch! Yes, this ffmpeg binary can only work on Android 4 till 6. I believe that ffmpeg 3.3 will work, try the prebuilt binaries on GitHub, or build it yourself. i have one question that your given GitHub link contains .so those are built for ffmpeg 3.3 ? Please let me know asap. or do you know the procedure to build .so ? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I checked the ARM build, it actually has --enable-asm. I believe that the whole crisis is about x86 emulator. I believe this should not bother us too much. I have not seen a live x86 device with Oreo yet. As for **mp2**, you probably can continue to use the [3.0.1](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) - it works for me on Oreo device.

Comment: @AlexCohn I downloaded your binaries 3.3 and I found that there is no prebuild binaries for armeabi-v7a-neon in assets folder. So I need those binaries in my app. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that the armeabi-v7a binary was built with neon enabled. Note that the devices with armv7 without neon are almost non-existent these days. The only SoC like that was Tegra-2, but it's really old.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks you alex those mp2 files working now on my Phone(in my android app). But now I am trying to play same mp2 files on android Emulator (Oreo and Nougat) and those are not working it give me error. So why this happening? what dependency should I give to play those mp2 files on emulator.

Comment: Just ignore the emulator for now; use an earlier platform to test this feature on emulator, and skip it on N and higher. Note that performance-wise, there is almost no correlation how this process works on an ARM device and on x86 emulator.

Comment: Anyone tried ffmpeg 3.3 and is it working on 7.1 - 8.1, if yes please let me know and also how I include those library and start with it.